# LoadRunner and JMS

Tags: jms, loadrunner

Does LoadRunner support testing of JMS Queues? What protocol do I need to cope with this task? Obviously without a GUI to test through (using http protocol) this is a challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have several paths here

(1) JMS Queue support in the web service virtual user

(2) JMS with Java Code in Java Template virtual User

(3) VB Code for Native queue support, bypassing the JMS mapping layer

(4) C Code for Native queue support, bypassing the JMS mapping layer

(5) Winsock (works for non secured MQ Queues...haven't tried it with other queue types)

I prefer options 5,3 and 2 in that order.   Option 1 always seems unnecessarily complex to me to get it to work. i.e. I usually have to call support for some exotic trick and I never want to call HP support because I know it will be a difficult series of conversations before I get to someone who can help.

Number 2 works quite well, but the reason why I leave it to last is I am a native thinker of C, so when I get to Java I have to think in C and then transpose to Java, so I take a productivity hit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the JMS Protocol Add In

http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/product/25384/JMS_datasheet_protocol_1225202153810.pdf